# Como saber se todas as labels com números estão preenchidas

Tags: c#

Tenho um cartão com números gerados aleatoriamente que quando são iguais ao número gerado no meio, tornam as labels laranja.

No entanto, eu queria fazer algo para quando todas as labels com números ficassem laranjas, aparecia uma `MessageBox` dizendo algo. Mas não sei verificar se estas estão todas a laranja. Como é que faço isso?

Só tenho isto para quando o texto das labels é igual ao número do meio.

```
foreach (Label lblCor in panel1.Controls)
    if (lblNum.Text == lblCor.Text)
        lblCor.BackColor = Color.Orange;
```

[image: Os cartões ão estes.]

Comment: Não seria porque você esta tentado colocar a sua lógica dentro de if (lblNum.Text == lblCor.Text), ou seja, só vai verificar quando o número do meio for igual.

Comment: Talvez seja isso... tentei também fazer de outra forma, mas não consegui. Tentei criar um int com um tamanho de 15 e sempre que uma label ficava laranja tirava 1 na int. Logo, quando tivesse 0, aparecerima uma MessageBox, mas não resultava

Comment: Você pode criar uma flag fora do for com o nome mostraMensagem = true e dentro do for você coloca o seguinte if (lblCor.BackColor != Color.Orange), se ele entrar neste if você seta a flag para falso, e embaixo do for você coloca outro if verificando a flag, ou seja, se ele entrar no if dentro do for é porque não foram preenchida todas as labels com laranja.

Comment: Eu nunca mexi com flags, não sei como é que se faz isso, mas posso tentar!

Comment: Flag é só um nome "bonitinho", flag é uma variável só isso

Comment: Isto foi o que entendi:

var mostraMensangem = true;

            foreach (Label lblCor in panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (lblNum.Text == lblCor.Text)
                    lblCor.BackColor = Color.Orange;

                if (lblCor.BackColor != Color.Orange)
                    mostraMensangem = false;
            }

            if (mostraMensangem == true)
                MessageBox.Show("Ganhou!");

Comment: Isso, funcionou?

Comment: Não! As labels ficaram laranjas, como era suposto, mas quando todas as labels com numeros ficaram laranjas, não aconteceu mais nada!

Comment: Você não consegue debuga para ver o comportamento do seu código?

Comment: vou exprimentar!

Comment: Após todos as labels ficarem laranjas, o programa continua a dar loop e nunca sai do foreach

Comment: acho que a resposta de vik ajudou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso o seu painel contenha apenas **Labels**, pode fazer o seguinte para contar quantas labels tem o `BackColor` a laranja:

```
int totalDeLaranjas = panel1.Controls.Cast<Label>().Count(lbl => lbl.BackColor == Color.Orange);
```

Comment: Acho que com isto vou conseguir o que quero, obrigado!

Comment: Vik, só tenho um problema, eu fiz um if(totalDeLaranjas == 15) e funciona. Só que quando uso uma MessageBox lá dentro, a mensagem não desaparece. Ou seja, mesmo depois de clicar em "Ok" na mensagem, ou tentar fechá-la, ela volta a aparecer. Eu percebo qual é o problema, mas não consigo resolvê-lo

Comment: Sem ver o codigo fica dificil saber qual o problema, pode postar o codigo do botão "novo numero", ou editar o post..

Comment: Outra coisa que você poderia melhorar era a criação dos cartões, por exemplo, cada coluna ter apenas numeros dessa dezena, e cada coluna ter pelo menos um numero.

Comment: Tenho isto:
if (totalDeLaranjas == 15)
                {
                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("O jogador 1 ganhou! Desejas jogar de novo?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {

                        this.Close();
                        Form1 inicio = new Form1();
                        inicio.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        this

Comment: Sim, tenho que fazer essa parte ainda :D

Comment: Sem saber o que está antes e onde se chama esse trecho de codigo fica dificil... o que podes pensar em fazer é criar um metodo com os valores iniciais "SetDefaultValues()", lá inicias / fazes reset de todas variavies e controlos e quando recebes "Yes" na mensagem chamas esse metodo, não sendo necessario estar a fechar e abrir o form de novo...

Comment: Hm... vou tentar isso, peço desculpa por não ser tão claro

Answer (score 2):

Baseando-me na resposta de @vik, outro LINQ possível de usar:

```
continuaWhile = 
    !panel1.Controls
        .OfType<Label>()
        .All(label => label.BackColor == Color.Orange);
```

e daí, no `while`, vai a condição:

```
bool continuaWhile = true;

while (continuaWhile)
{
    // Faz o que tem que fazer, aqui.

    // Por último, verifica se continua iterando o laço.
    continuaWhile =
        !panel1.Controls
            .OfType<Label>()
            .All(label => label.BackColor == Color.Orange);
}
```